# Given two collections A & B: want to output the inner join, elements in A that were not in B, elements in B that were not in A

Tags: c#, linq

Given two collections A & B, I want to output:
1. their inner join (say on a field called Id)
2. those elements in A that could not be found in B
3. those elements in B that could not be found in A
What is the most efficient way to do this?

When I say those elements in A that could not be found in B, I mean those elements that could not be "inner-joined" with B

Comment: are `A` and `B` collections of the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'd write this:

```
public class DeltaSet<T>
{
    public ISet<T> FirstItems { get; private set; }
    public ISet<T> SecondItems { get; private set; }
    public ISet<Tuple<T, T>> IntersectedItems { get; private set; }

    // T is the type of the objects, U is the key used to determine equality
    public static DeltaSet<T> GetDeltaSet<T, U>(IDictionary<U, T> first,
                                                IDictionary<U, T> second)
    {
        var firstUniques = new HashSet<T>(
            first.Where(x => !second.ContainsKey(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value));

        var secondUniques = new HashSet<T>(
            second.Where(x => !first.ContainsKey(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value));

        var intersection = new HashSet<Tuple<T, T>>(
            second.Where(x => first.ContainsKey(x.Key)).Select(x =>
                Tuple.Create(first[x.Key], x.Value)));

        return new DeltaSet<T> { FirstItems = firstUniques,
                                 SecondItems = secondUniques,
                                 IntersectedItems = intersection };
    }

    public static DeltaSet<IDClass> GetDeltas(IEnumerable<IDClass> first,
                                              IEnumerable<IDClass> second)
    {
        return GetDeltaSet(first.ToDictionary(x => x.ID),
                           second.ToDictionary(x => x.ID));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the inner join, have a look at the `.Join()` extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344797.aspx

For the second 2 outputs, have a look at the `.Except()` extension method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx

For examples of most of the LINQ queries, have a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: Actually, he should be using Intersect

Comment: @Chris: If he uses intersect, he'll get the common values from both collections.From the 101 Samples page: 'This sample uses Intersect to create one sequence that contains the common values shared by both arrays.'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have class A for elements in collection A and class B in collection B

```
class AB {
  public A PartA;
  public B PartB;
  // Constructor
};

public void ManyJoin (List<A> colA, List<B> colB)
{
  List<AB> innerJoin = new List<AB>();
  List<A> leftJoin = new List<A>();
  List<B> rightJoin = new List<B>();
  bool[] foundB = new bool[colB.Count];

  foreach (A itemA in colA)
  {
    int i = colB.FindIndex(itemB => itemB.ID == itemA.ID);
    if (i >= 0)
    {
      innerJoin.Add (new AB(itemA, colB[i]));
      foundB[i] = true;
    }
    else
      leftJoin.Add(itemA);
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < foundB.count; j++)
  {
    if (!foundB[j])
      rightJoin.Add(colB[j]);
  }
}
```

This is one possible way. Whether it is optimum or not, I'm not sure, it does the job.